# How to make double quotes and single quotes be handled the same

Tags: codemirror, codemirror-modes

We have an issue finding a way to make codemirror behave the same for single and double quote strings.

[image]

It would have been been a quick css hack but, for double quotes the css generated has no tags around it.

The single quotes have a class called "cm-string" that would be nice to have on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it is like this. I use the theme light, in the theme / light.css file line:
.cm-s-light span.cm-string {color: # 3ad900; }
it displays me like on the screen "" and "the same in green
Search in your theme file.
[image]

AND
for file sql.js in line 57:

```
 } else if (ch == "'" || (ch == '"' && support.doubleQuote)) {
```

remove:

```
 && support.doubleQuote
```

so that it stays:

```
 } else if (ch == "'" || (ch == '"')) {
```

and you will get the desired effect in SQL mode.

[image]

For TCL
Replace line 45 tcl.js:

```
   if ((ch == '"' || ch == "'") && state.inParams) {
```

such as line:

```
   if ((ch == '"' || ch == "'")) {
```

Comment: amazing, I need this with tcl instead of sql, do you have an idea on how to do it there?

Comment: Yes, see answer.